# programatically generating a link in asp.net-mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I just get the URL link to a specific route programatically?

I want to do a response.redirect (URL TO ROUTE);

Answer (score 2):

You can use Url.Action.

Try [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190916191225/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/liammclennan/archive/2008/05/21/122298.aspx)